# Angular 11 error : Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular11

[image: Error message]

I have the same page which works fine but I don't know why this one is not working. It looks like the error happens before the array gets filled. Why? On my other page, it is the same service and it works. Thanks for your help.

#### HTML

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>UserID</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let printShopPortalUser of printShopPortalUsers; let i = index">
    <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
    <td>{{ printShopPortalUser.userID }}</td>
  
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

#### Angular

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      NgbModule
        
    ],
    declarations: [
    ]
})

printShopPortalUsers: UserPrintShop[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
//The first method is returning an empty array ! while it works on another page
    //this.printShopPortalUserService.findAll().pipe(first()).subscribe(printShopPortalUsers => this.printShopPortalUsers = printShopPortalUsers);

//This second method returns an array but the tr error happens before
    this.printShopPortalUserService.findAll().pipe(first()).subscribe((res:UserPrintShop[])=>{
      this.printShopPortalUsers = res;
      console.log(res);
    })
    console.log(this.printShopPortalUsers);


}
```

Comment: Please try to import BrowserModule in your root module, add CommonModule to the child module.

Comment: Hi Kevi Zhang, yes, Browser module is in root module and I have imported common module only, but it is the same error.

Comment: how many module do you have in your project is it just one ? try to run this command `ng build --prod` what do you get

Comment: I get errors which I don't get in development src/app/services/UserPrintShopService.ts:18:33 - error TS2339: Property 'api' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

18     super(_http, `${environment.api.baseUrl}usersprintshop`);    I get that for the other pages and services which are working ok in development mode.

Comment: if it possible upload an example of a light demo so we can check it , stackblitz.com is good place to create a demo

Comment: Doubt if its causing the issue - I would have made the CommonModule comment as above - but I notice that your th's and tds do not match - in your thead - you have 3 th's and in the body - only two td's per tr.

You should a) remove a th from the thead, b) add a td to the tr, or c) add a colspan of "2" to the td

Comment: malbarmavi, i will do it in a 2h and put the link here.

Answer (score 3):

you need to import **CommonModule**

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      NgbModule,
      CommonModule  
    ],
    declarations: [
    ]
}
```

Comment: Also tried this but still getting the same error. thanks for your help.

Comment: are you using lazy modules ?

Comment: I don't know. How to verify this ? I have added the picture

Comment: I'd recommend to double check if you import CommonModule in the module where your component is declared. That's really the the standard problem.

Comment: Christoph, yes it is imported where the component is declared.

Answer (score 0):

in html add a truthy verfication to printShopPortalUsers

```
<tbody *ngIf="printShopPortalUsers">
          <tr *ngFor="let printShopPortalUser of printShopPortalUsers; let i = index">
               <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
               <td>{{ printShopPortalUser.userID }}</td>
          </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found out where the issue was.
I am using an angular template which is called "Paper Dashboard"

It has a file called "admin-layout.module.ts"

This is the module which imports the common module.

I just had to do the import of my component here and declare it here as well this and it worked

```
import { PrintShopPortalUserComponent } from '../../pages/printShopPortalUsers/printShopPortalUserComponent'; 

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(AdminLayoutRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  declarations: [
   ..
    PrintShopPortalUserComponent,
  ..
  ]
})
```